# Openlayers problem loading .svg Icon Feature

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, openlayers

I'm trying to load an icon from my files like the openlayers example at the link below

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html?q=icon

It's working when a build with "npm start" and connect at the localhost (http://localhost:1234/), but if I build with "npm run build" and load the index.html at "dist" folder, it doesn't show my icon feature

I've checked and it's ok the name and folder, and it's working with the command "npm start" and the source is like this "src: 'data/icon.png'"

best regards

Comment: where is data directory located?. is it in assets?.

Comment: the directory is ok, with the npm start it works fine, but if I open the index.html (ex. firefox), it didn't appears